# Broken loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am working on learning python (version 3), and as you are probably aware, one of the exercises is to create a game of rock paper scissors lizard spock (rpsls) I was required to start with the if statements featured below, then modify the code to include loops and use a random function to add a computer player. I have spent a few days adjusting the code and googling things, but I have not been able to fix the break in the loop. It gets stuck asking player one for input endlessly and never loads the comparison with player2 or finishes the round. I realize this is a messy way to code the game, but I would like to keep the formatting if possible.

```
        import random

print("")
print("**** Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors ****")
print("")



inputOK = False
player2choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']
while inputOK == False:
    stringPlayer1 = input("Player 1, choose: rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock: ")

    stringPlayer2 = random.choice(player2choices)
if stringPlayer1 == stringPlayer2:
    print("Tie: Both players chose:" +
          stringPlayer1)

elif stringPlayer1 == 'scissors' and stringPlayer2 == 'paper':
    print("Player 1 wins: scissors cuts paper.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'paper' and stringPlayer2 == 'rock':
    print("Player 1 wins: paper covers rock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'rock' and stringPlayer2 == 'lizard':
    print("Player 1 wins: rock crushes lizard.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'lizard' and stringPlayer2 == 'spock':
    print("Player 1 wins: lizard poisons spock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'spock' and stringPlayer2 == 'scissors':
    print("Player 1 wins: Spock smashes scissors.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'scissors' and stringPlayer2 == 'lizard':
    print("Player 1 wins: scissors decapitates lizard.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'lizard' and stringPlayer2 == 'paper':
    print("Player 1 wins: lizard eats paper.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'paper' and stringPlayer2 == 'spock':
    print("Player 1 wins: paper disproves Spock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'spock' and stringPlayer2 == 'rock':
    print("Player 1 wins: Spock vaporizes rock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'rock' and stringPlayer2 == 'scissors':
    print("Player 1 wins: rock crushes scissors.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'paper' and stringPlayer2 == 'scissors':
    print("Player 2 wins: scissors cuts paper.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'rock' and stringPlayer2 == 'paper':
    print("Player 2 wins: paper covers rock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'lizard' and stringPlayer2 == 'rock':
    print("Player 2 wins: rock crushes lizard.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'spock' and stringPlayer2 == 'lizard':
    print("Player 2 wins: lizard poisons spock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'scissors' and stringPlayer2 == 'spock':
    print("Player 2 wins: Spock smashes scissors.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'lizard' and stringPlayer2 == 'scissors':
    print("Player 2 wins: scissors decapitates lizard.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'paper' and stringPlayer2 == 'lizard':
    print("Player 2 wins: lizard eats paper.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'spock' and stringPlayer2 == 'paper':
    print("Player 2 wins: paper disproves Spock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'rock' and stringPlayer2 == 'spock':
    print("Player 2 wins: Spock vaporizes rock.")

elif stringPlayer1 == 'scissors' and stringPlayer2 == 'rock':
    print("Player 2 wins: rock crushes scissors.")

else:
    inputOK = False
    print("Error: Not a valid choice.")

quit = input("Do you want to quit? ")
if quit.lower() == "y" or quit.lower() == "yes":
    done = True
```

Comment: in python, [indentation matters](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=indentation#indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User will be stuck in infinite loop unless somewhere *within* the while loop the condition is changed by setting `inputOK = True`.

Before that you need to determine what will be the condition for valid input, such as user input being one of the valid choices  (`if stringPlayer1 in player1choices`):

```
player2choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock']
player1choices = player2choices

while inputOK == False:
    stringPlayer1 = input("Player 1, choose: rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock: ")
    if stringPlayer1 in player1choices: # a condition for valid input?
        inputOK = True
    stringPlayer2 = random.choice(player2choices)
```

That should at least fix the broken loop and allow you to move along developing the game more.

Comment: Wow. Amazing how big a difference that made. That fixed it. Thanks. Are there any other languages where indentation makes a difference? Most just ignore white space so Python is interesting.

Comment: I agree,  strict indentation rules seem unique to only python (oh, and this answer [Do you find languages with indentation requirements cumbersome?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7168/228211) mentions only Makefiles, but that's more of a building tool) so outside of python, you're right indentation is ignored. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will continue looping until your variable, inputOk, equals True. Your error is that inputOK is not being updated to True when the player wants to end the game. Perhaps you meant to set inputOk equal to True instead of done?

`quit = input("Do you want to quit? ")
if quit.lower() == "y" or quit.lower() == "yes":
    inputOk = True`

Edit: Also as already mentioned, you must indent in python. Any code not indented under while statement will not loop.